# How to statically render dynamic pages using next.js, such that the dynamic pages data is not available during build time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

According to the current docs of next.js, dynamic routes are handled by providing the route data to `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`.

What concept will enable me to implement dynamic routes with or without using `getStaticProps()` and `getStaticPaths()`, when the route data is being fetched from a database during build time?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. You'll use `getStaticPaths` / `getStaticProps` to fetch data from your database. Then, you forward props to your React component (with `getStaticPaths`) and generate the routes you want (with `getStaticProps`).

For example, let's say you have a file `blog/[slug].js`.

If you visit `/blog/first`, that will forward the variable `first` as a parameter to `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` as `slug`. You can then use that value to fetch information about the given post (or anything else in your database).

Example:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/blog-starter/pages/posts/%5Bslug%5D.js

Comment: Now that the parameter "first" is passed to getStaticProps/getStaticPaths, it will compute something using that value and return data.What should I do when I'm fetching that computing value from a database and it's not present during build time?

Comment: Inside `getStaticPaths`, you would fetch all of the values from your database to _generate_ the parameters like "first".

Comment: What do I do when **getStaticPaths()** returns undefined due to me using an asynchronous database call to fetch data?

Comment: Make `getStaticPaths()` async, for example `export async function getStaticPaths()`

Comment: Tried that. Since the asnc db call takes time to execute,the return is run before it making paths value null.If i add the return statement inside ".then()" format,it is an error.Can you help out?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn more about async/await first: https://javascript.info/async-await

And then check out the same examples in the Next.js repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/blog-starter